# bread that does not get moldy

Tags: bread, mold, spoilage, rye

How can a bread have an expiration date of one year into the future?? The bread in questions is Deutsche Küche rye bread (from Aldi).  Yes, it is a dense bread, but it is not dry like a cracker, so there seems to be enough moisture for mold to grow.  There are no preservatives.

Edit (pictures added):
[image: Deutsche Küche in package]
[image: Deutsche Küche slice]

Comment: BTW: it does look like an authentic Schwarzbrot indeed.

Answer (score 10):

It's the baking and packaging.

These dark rye breads are baked for a very long time (effectively pasteurizing them) and then sealed in their packaging. If you do this in a commercial setting that can ensure a mostly contaminant-free environement, such breads can last a long time.

Once you break the seal by opening the pack, your bread will get moldy like all other breads.

---

The very dense crumb structure and compounds in the whole-grain rye used might to a certain degree inhibit the growth of mold, but not enough to make the bread last for months.